# Smarty replace text with urls to links except images

Tags: php, regex, smarty, smarty3

I have text like this:

```
some text

https://zoom.us/rec/share/hHhxMEBNpVO3wcMUuYcakJFcm6QdJYm3ZU8LVs6Q_atdsRfKE97VjHZOQcFV0Avl.J7s0D8ABUtF28-SX?startTime=1619246702000

<img src="https://clip2net.com/clip/7777/8074e-clip-78kb.png?nocache=1">
```

I need all url in text replace to link, so `https://zoom.us/rec/share/hHhxMEBNpVO3wcMUuYcakJFcm6QdJYm3ZU8LVs6Q_atdsRfKE97VjHZOQcFV0Avl.J7s0D8ABUtF28-SX?startTime=1619246702000` will be

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://zoom.us/rec/share/hHhxMEBNpVO3wcMUuYcakJFcm6QdJYm3ZU8LVs6Q_atdsRfKE97VjHZOQcFV0Avl.J7s0D8ABUtF28-SX?startTime=1619246702000">https://zoom.us/rec/share/hHhxMEBNpVO3wcMUuYcakJFcm6QdJYm3ZU8LVs6Q_atdsRfKE97VjHZOQcFV0Avl.J7s0D8ABUtF28-SX?startTime=1619246702000</a>
```

Now i use this code:

```
{$projectDescription|regex_replace:"#([[:alpha:]]+://[^<>[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]/])#":"<a href=\"\\0\" TARGET=\"_blank\">\\0</a>"}
```

But this code also replace my img src to href.
So issue is how replace all urls except images?

Comment: Or with this code `{assign var=html_links value=preg_replace('"\b(https?://\S+)"', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $projectDescription)}` it also doesnt work

Comment: Can anybody help me please? I am stuck with it(

Comment: A simple way to do this would be to add a requirement for a whitespace character \s at the beginning of your match like \s(https?://\S+) This will make your example work, but if you have situations like <p>https://zoom.us/.. this will not work.

Comment: Have you tried telling the regex to avoid image extensions? "png", "jpg", "gif", etc?